# how can I use javascript in .hbs handlebars files?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have an .hbs file and in this file I can access the username by typing `{{username}}`.
Now I add a script tag to my .hbs file (like adding script tags to html files) and I want to write javascript in this tag. I have tested:

`alert(5);`

and it worked. Now I want to access the `{{username}}` variable in my script tag but typing `{{username}}` doesn't return the username. How can I access this variable?

```
{{username}}

<script type="text/javascript">

var temp = Handlebars.compile('{{username}}');

var username = temp({});
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/users/"+ username +"/summary.json", function (data) {
    num= data.topics[0].id;
});

 </script>
```

I want to print the num variable in my .hbs file near {{username}} but I don't know how ?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Don't do this. Just put JS in a JS file where it belongs. You never need to do this. What is the larger context of why you want to compile a template in a script embedded in a template?

Comment: @torazaburo this is a discourse plugin to show each users score on their card and this file is my outlet connector. I don't know how to do what you said

Answer (score 1):

```
{{{username}}} // triple brackets to avoid handlebars from scaping it
...

<div> id=Username value={{{username}}} style="visibility:hidden" </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

let a = document.querySelector('#body')
username = a.innertHTML // or whatever you need to get the content of the variable //username, in my case it was a long html paragraph.

 </script>
```